# Unable to read data about FCN,i don't know how to do.the result is:Found pickle file! 0 0

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
import glob

import TensorflowUtils as utils
DATA_URL = 'http:\\data.csail.mit.edu\\places\\ADEchallenge\\ADEChallengeData2016.zip'

#download and read dataset
def read_dataset(data_dir):
    pickle_filename = "MITSceneParsing.pickle"
    pickle_filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, pickle_filename)
    if not os.path.exists(pickle_filepath):
        utils.maybe_download_and_extract(data_dir, DATA_URL, is_zipfile=True)
        SceneParsing_folder = os.path.splitext(DATA_URL.split("/")[-1])[0]
        result = create_image_lists(os.path.join(data_dir, SceneParsing_folder))
        print ("Pickling ...")
        with open(pickle_filepath, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(result, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    else:
        print ("Found pickle file!")

    with open(pickle_filepath, 'rb') as f:
        result = pickle.load(f)
        training_records = result['training']
        validation_records = result['validation']
        del result

    return training_records, validation_records
train_records, valid_records = read_dataset('Data_zoo/MIT_SceneParsing')   
print(len(train_records))
print(len(valid_records))
```

the result is:Found pickle file! 0 0
why the lens about train_records and valid_records are 0? 
i don't know whree is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is right. The bug is in '`create_image_lists`'.
Note this code in create_image_lists:

```
filename = os.path.splitext(f.split('/')[-1])[0]
```

This is no problem in Linux, but in windows, the separator is '`\\`', so you should modify this code to:

```
filename = os.path.splitext(f.split('\\')[-1])[0]
```

Then delete this file 'MITSceneParsing.pickle', and run read_dataset again.

Comment: By the way, ID xiaoxiannv可还行！